# From List<Foo> to Map<String, List<Foo>>: looking for a better implementation

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream, lambdaj

Let me show you my code:

**Class Foo**

```
public class Foo {

    String code;
    String value;

    public Foo(String code, String value) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.value = value;
    }
    // getters/setters
}
```

**Main method** (focus on `getFooMultiMapCode()` method):

```
public class FooMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo1 = new Foo("100","foo1");
    Foo foo2 = new Foo("200","foo2");
    Foo foo3 = new Foo("300","foo3");
    Foo foo4 = new Foo("100","foo4");
    Foo foo5 = new Foo("100","foo5");
    Foo foo6 = new Foo("200","foo6");
    List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5,foo6);  
    Map<String,List<Foo>> fooCodeMap = getFooMultiMapCode(foos);
    System.out.println(fooCodeMap);
}

private static Map<String, List<Foo>> getFooMultiMapCode(List<Foo> foos) {
    Map<String, List<Foo>> fooMultiMapCode = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
    for(Foo foo:foos){
        List<Foo> list = fooMultiMapCode.get(foo.getCode());
        if(list==null){
            list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
            list.add(foo);
            fooMultiMapCode.put(foo.getCode(), list);
        }
        else {
            list.add(foo);
        }
    }
    return fooMultiMapCode;
}
}
```

Main prints correctly this string:

```
{100=[foo1, foo4, foo5], 200=[foo2, foo6], 300=[foo3]}
```

I would like to rewrite `getFooMultiMapCode` method in a more succint way using for example java8 or also libraries such lambdaj, guava, etc but I **don't want to change method signature**.

Comment: The non-stream variant: `for(Foo foo:foos) fooMultiMapCode.computeIfAbsent(foo.getCode(), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(foo);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution with Java 8 and [`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
return foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getCode, Collectors.toList()));
```

Or simply with [`groupingBy(classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) as [@Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) noticed:

```
return foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getCode));
```

Comment: Java 8 is definitely marginally more succinct than previous versions...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on @Holgers comment: Non-stream version if you prefer loops - still `java8`, though:

```
private static Map<String, List<Foo>> getFooMultiMapCode(List<Foo> foos) {
    Map<String, List<Foo>> fooMultiMapCode = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
    for(Foo foo : foos){
        fooMultiMapCode.computeIfAbsent(foo.getCode(), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(foo);
    }
    return fooMultiMapCode;
}
```

or even

```
private static Map<String, List<Foo>> getFooMultiMapCode(List<Foo> foos) {
    Map<String, List<Foo>> fooMultiMapCode = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
    foos.forEach(foo -> fooMultiMapCode.computeIfAbsent(foo.getCode(), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(foo));
    return fooMultiMapCode;
}
```

I still prefer the stream version, though.